# Flask SQLAlchemy query with concatenated columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a models like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    
    def full_name(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

I want to get the `full_name` method in a query, I try it like it:

```
user = db.session.query(User.full_name()).all()
```

But I get this error message:

```
TypeError: full_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Then I try to call the function without brackets:

```
user = db.session.query(User.full_name).all()
```

Then I got this error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<function User.full_name at 0x7f265960aae8>'
```

So, what is the correct way to query `full_name()` method in the User model..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this.  Firstly, a [hybrid attribute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html), a property that defines `full_name` on an instance and on the class (for querying).

This example is pure SQLAlchemy, but the hybrid attributes should be the same in Flask-SQLAlchemy.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext import hybrid

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users' 
                                                                                                                                                                        
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = sa.Column(sa.String)
    last_name = sa.Column(sa.String)

    @hybrid.hybrid_property
    def full_name(self):  
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

users = session.query(User).filter_by(full_name='Joan Doe').all()
```

Credit to [Ilja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%C3%A4) for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842652/flask-sqlalchemy-query-with-concatenated-columns/57843025#comment102114354_57843025) that this can be done using a single method in this case.  This works because SQLAlchemy maps the `+` [operator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#operators) to the database's `CONCAT` function.  If this weren't the case, an additional property decorated with `hybrid.expression` would be necessary to implement the behaviour at the class level.

SQLAlchemy inserts the necessary expressions into SQL statements as required, for example:

```sql
SELECT users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name 
FROM users 
WHERE users.first_name || ? || users.last_name = ?
```

Another way to achieve this is by defining a [column_property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property):

```py
from sqlalchemy import orm

class User(Base):
    ...
    full_name = orm.column_property(first_name + " " + last_name)
```

This inserts an expression into *all* queries on the model, so

```py
query = sa.select(User)
```

will generate this SQL:

```sql
SELECT users.first_name || ? || users.last_name AS anon_1,
       users.id, 
       users.first_name, 
       users.last_name 
FROM users
```

Finally, there are [computed columns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html?highlight=computed#computed-columns-generated-always-as).  These are conceptually similar to column properties, but implemented on the database side (provided the database supports the required syntax).  The database may or may not physically store the computed value; it may be possible to condition this behaviour by passing the `persisted` boolean keyword argument to `Computed`.

```py
class User(Base):
    ...
    full_name = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.Computed(first_name + ' ' + last_name))
```

Comment: In this case a single method would do as well :) (the one used for expression would work for both, I think it's even the example in docs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@classmethod`.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)

    @classmethod
    def full_name_filter(cls, fname, lname):
        return (cls.first_name == fname, cls.last_name == lname)
```

Then

```
user = db.session.query(User).filter(*User.full_name_filter("first", "last")).all()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your participation to answers my question, but I still got the same error:
`TypeError: full_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

and for more informations, I query it in different module, not in the class itself.